# Как сделать просмотр профиля пользователя?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Всем привет! Я - новичок и решил создать свой сайт. Перейду сразу к теме вопроса. Я не могу сделать профиль пользователя таким образом ../users/1 где 1 - id пользователя. Вот так я умею делать ../users.php?=1 , но мне так не нужно. Мой index:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/')
    $page = 'home';
   else 
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);


session_start();

include 'config.php';

if (file_exists("all/$page.php"))
    include "all/$page.php";
else if ($_SESSION['user'] and file_exists("auth/$page.php"))
    include "auth/$page.php";
else if (!$_SESSION['user']['id'] and file_exists("guest/$page.php"))
    include "guest/$page.php";
else
    require 'all/404.php';
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если правильно Вас понял, то `htaccess - rewrite rules` погуглите..или как то так, не ошибетесь )

Answer (score 0):

используйте altorouter можно найти в composer и документацию по нему также без проблем там сможете найти. а так вам нужно настроить как вам писали в комментариях htaccess rewrite rules если вы используете apache если nginx

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

[Подробней читайте тут по nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)